# IBM Blue mix: An error occurred while communicating with the server

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to sign up for the IBM blue mix services (free trial). When I try to do so, I am getting the below error:

> "Console.ng.bluemix.net says: An error occured while communicating with the server. Please try again. (Payload is not valid. IBM ID password can 'only contain numbers, upper and lower case letters, hyphens, underscore and periods"

My id is really plain. It's something like `abcde@gmail.com`

Inspite of trying with other email ids I am getting the error. First time to blue mix.

Comment: The error message suggests it is your password that is causing the issue, not the user id.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates an issue with your password, ensure that your password does not contain characters outside of what is mentioned in the error message. The issue is not reported on the Email ID value which is the IBMid.